# Do 'where` conditions count affect select speed in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, query-performance

There is a mysql Person table like below.  id is primary, indexed. But other columns are not indexed..

```
id         name         surname         age          city          branch
1          John         Black           34           London        driver
2          Lara         Croft           28           New York      teacher
3          Ahmad        Hasan           41           Doha          doctor
...
1000.000......
```

My Question is when I make execute `select` query with `where` clause with multiple conditions, does it decrease select speed.
For example which one is faster?

```
Select * From Person Where age > 30
```

or

```
Select * from Person Where age > 20 AND city = 'London' AND name = 'John' AND branch = 'doctor' AND ...
```

Could you tell me which one will be faster?

Comment: Depending on your data and indexes, latter one is probably faster if it can use better indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without indexes, any `WHERE` clause causes a table scan. That is, to satisfy the query the server must examine every row in the table. So the search operations you have shown take on the order of the same time as one another.

It also takes time to send a large result set from the MySQL server to the client. Fewer rows in the result set make that part of satisfying your query faster.

Pro tip: avoid SELECT * when dealing tables over about 100 rows long. Instead give the names of the columns you actually need.